# Navigation to new Page fails: Automatically returns to previous page on Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, navigationservice

I have created a Pivot app, launch HomePage and using a Button, I navigate to a new blank page.

```
private void Forgot_Password_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ForgotPasswordPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The new page is shown, but after a while, it terminates and returns back the previous page. I also get the following error:

```
The thread 0x990 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Has anyone experienced a similar behaviour?

However, if I start this page directly (ForgotPasswordPage) (instead of HomePage), it starts normally.

**UPDATED**:

I noticed that this happens to any page I navigate from the the page with the Pivot control. Does this has any connection with the problem?

**UPDATED #2**:

I tried the following flow:
Let's assume I have the following Pages:

- MainPage
- HomePage (this is the one with the pivot)
- LoginPage

I start MainPage and then using an action on the app bar I navigate to Home Page. Everything is ok so far. Then using a button I navigate to LoginPage which is a simple blank Page. After a while this Page terminates and I automatically return to Home Page.

Then I tried to start LoginPage from MainPage. The Login Page starts normally but after few seconds it terminates and I return to the HomePage which I had never navigated to!!!!

Does this help to understand what goes so wrong?

**UPDATED #3**

I setup the whole project from the beginning and then started adding the code from the previous project. I found that this behaviour was generated due a DispatchTimer I had, which I had never stopped. Fixed it and now the problem is solved. Thank you all for your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting. Does this happen on both the emulator and the device?

Comment: I haven't tested on device yet. I run Visual Studio Express for Windows on Windows 8.1 running on VMWare Fusion 5.

Comment: Does it happen also on WP8.1 (you tagged it)? Does it happen when you navigate from Page without Pivot control?

Comment: I have not tried WP8.1 yet. Please check updated answer for a strange flow I get.

Comment: Check also if there isn't something strange in `App.xaml.cs`. Set few breakpoints and see how navigation goes. And as suggested above, if possible try on a device. You can also share a code so it would be possible to check on other device/computer.

Answer (score 3):

The  problem appeard to be a DispatchTimer that keeped running
as user updated in the question.

> UPDATED #3
>
> I setup the whole project from the beginning and then started adding
>   the code from the previous project. I found that this behaviour was
>   generated due a DispatchTimer I had, which I had never stopped. Fixed
>   it and now the problem is solved.

The solution to this specific issue would be to manage carefully any long running operations inside your application.